# How can I scrape the first link of a google search with beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to make a script that will scrape the first link of a google search so that it will give me back only the first link so I can run a search in the terminal and look at the link later on with the search term. I'm struggling to only get the first result. This is the closest thing I've got so far.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

research_later = "hiya"
goog_search = "https://www.google.co.uk/search?sclient=psy-ab&client=ubuntu&hs=k5b&channel=fs&biw=1366&bih=648&noj=1&q=" + research_later


r = requests.get(goog_search)    
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)  

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print research_later + " :"+link.get('href')
```

Comment: Why is the google search URL so long with so many different parameters? (I'm just curious)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems like Google use `cite` tag to save the link, so we can just use `soup.find('cite').text` like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

research_later = "hiya"
goog_search = "https://www.google.co.uk/search?sclient=psy-ab&client=ubuntu&hs=k5b&channel=fs&biw=1366&bih=648&noj=1&q=" + research_later


r = requests.get(goog_search)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
print soup.find('cite').text
```

Output is:

```
www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hiya
```

Comment: this is not working now..why? it returning the error like  '''print (soup.find('cite').text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text''''

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [`select_one()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) for selecting `CSS` selectors or [`find()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) `bs4` methods to get only one element from the page. To grab `CSS` selectors you can use [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) extension.

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Search-Scrape-First-Occurrence-python-serpapi#bs4_result.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=ice cream', headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

# locating .tF2Cxc class
# calling for <a> tag and then calling for 'href' attribute
link = soup.select('.yuRUbf a')['href']
print(link)

# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_cream
```

---

Alternatively, you can do the same thing by using [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The main difference is that everything (selecting, bypass blocks, proxy rotation, and more) is already done for the end-user with a JSON output.

Code to integrate:

```py
params = {
    "engine": "google",
    "q": "ice cream",
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

# [0] - first index from the search results
link = results['organic_results'][0]['link']
print(link)

# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_cream
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.